# Peculiarity about a system of three electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-calculus, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Consider three (or any number bigger than 2) electrons without spatial degrees of freedom, thus the only degree of freedom is the spins. The Hilbert space is then formed by the tensor product of the space of each electron. Now according to my literature about the so-called antisymmetric tensor, that there are no antisymmetric tensor can be formed if the number of vectors to be tensor-multiplied is bigger than the dimension of each vector space. If applied to my example in the beginning, it seems that I cannot form an antisymmetric state in the system of three electrons because the number of ket to be tensor-multiplied is three (there are three electrons) while the dimension of each is 2 (due to spin 1/2). If this is true, then is three electron system without spatial degrees of freedom impossible? But this is strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is not possible to construct a totally antisymmetric spin state with more than two electrons. This is just a statement of Pauli's exclusion principle.

Comment: Does that mean that inclusion of the spatial part of the wave function is essential in creating a 3-electron state?

Comment: Wait, wait, wait...
After some times pondering on it, if I stick on $|\pm\rangle |\pm\rangle |\pm\rangle$ basis, indeed it doesn't seem possible to construct an anti-symmetric state. But if I introduce another state, say $|\pi\rangle$ which is some linear combination of $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, I can actually form an antisymmetric state, which is 
$$
|A\rangle = |+\rangle |-\rangle |\pi\rangle + |\pi\rangle |-\rangle |+\rangle + |-\rangle |\pi\rangle |+\rangle - |\pi\rangle |-\rangle |+\rangle -|-\rangle |+\rangle |\pi\rangle - |+\rangle |\pi\rangle |-\rangle
$$
What do you think?

Comment: @nougako indeed it doesn't violate Pauli principle: all three electrons are in different single-particle states, so the total state can be antisymmetrized.

Comment: @nougako No, you cannot. Expand $|\pi\rangle$ as an arbitrary linear combination of $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ and you will see that $|A\rangle = 0$. If you have a vector space $V$, the antisymmetric product states are a subspace of $V\otimes V$. For a 2d space, $\text{Asymm}(V\otimes V)$ is one-dimensional, and so $\text{Asymm}(V\otimes V\otimes V)$ is zero-dimensional.

Comment: There seem to have formed a pro and contra here.
@LukePritchett, I don't understand the conditional statement of your last sentence "For a 2d space, $\textrm{Asymm}(V\otimes V)$ is one-dimensional, and so $\textrm{Asymm}(V\otimes V\otimes V)$ is zero-dimensional. You made it sounds like the dimensionality of $\textrm{Asymm}(V\otimes V)$ has an implication on the dimensionality of  $\textrm{Asymm}(V\otimes V\otimes V)$. Can you explain how they are connected?

Comment: @nougako I was sloppy and I'm not sure the implication is correct. However, $\text{Asymm}(V\otimes V\otimes V)$ is zero-dimensional if $V$ is 2-dimensional. To see this, try to construct a basis. Or, try https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/12/23/antisymmetric-tensors/

Comment: I don't know if $\mathrm{Asymm}(V\otimes V)$ is standard notation. At least in mathematics the object you are talking about (exterior algebra) would be denoted $\Lambda^3(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and it is quite easy to see that it is a trivial vector space (dimension zero) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Basis_and_dimension

Comment: @Ruslan There are *two* single particle states, the electrons cannot be in three different (linearly independent) states. In fact as Luke Pritchett pointed out, $|A\rangle=0$.

Comment: I believe fqq and Luke were correct, namely there can be no antisymmetric state formed by three electrons without spatial wavefunction. Then this implies, IMO, that any atom with $Z>2$ such that the nuclear attractive force is not strong enough so as to make spin-orbit coupling influential, must always have antisymmetric spatial wavefunction for all eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, because the spin wavefunction will always be symmetric. Am I right

Comment: I don't see why the state needs to be decomposable in spatial wavefunction $\otimes$ spin state (or why the spin part needs to be symmetric).

Comment: The inability to antisymmetrize 3 objects that take 2 values is a statement of the pigeonhole principle not the Pauli principle.